# Terraform deploy ingress-nginx helm chart fails

Tags: nginx-ingress

When trying to deploy `ingress-nginx` helm chart with Terraform on EKS cluster fails with the message: `Failed build model due to unable to resolve at least one subnet`

Versions:
Terraform: 1.4.6
EKS: 1.27 (eks.2)
AWS provider: 4.47
Helm provider: 2.10.1
Kubernetes provider: 2.21.1

Terraform code snippet which fails with context deadline exceeded due to the `Failed build model due to unable to resolve at least one subnet` in the `kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx`:

```
resource "helm_release" "ingress_nginx" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.this]

  name      = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace = "ingress-nginx"

  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  timeout    = 600
  version    = "4.7.0"
}
```

Note: External IP is in the pending state. I checked the EIP service limit utilization, and it is way below the current limit.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the missing subnet tags. To be specific `kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster_name>=shared`. Though it is not required by the core EKS stuff, as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html), apparently some NGINX components rely on this old tagging technique.